# How to generate a controller with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails (rubygems-1.8.24) successfully on
Windows 7.

Now I need to generate a 'controller home index' on command prompt. I
created a project folder called 'rails-projects' and successfully
created a project called 'quizzes-on-rails'.

At:

```
C:\rails-projects\quizzes-on-rails
```

I type:

```
ruby script/generate controller home index
```

And I get the following message:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/generate <LoadError>
```

I edited PATH by including C:\rails-projects\quizzes-on-rails

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: script/generate sounds like you are reading an old tutorial for rails 1 or 2.  Be sure to focus on version 3 or 4, there's no need to be learning the old methods. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start cmd prompt with rails or open the rails command prompt and run:

```
rails g controller Foo home index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
rails g controller <ControllerName> [valid actions]
```

e.g.:

```
rails g controller Posts index show destroy
```